# Sqlite+ Sinatra - Database file is not getting created with DataMapper.setup

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra

I am creating one web application in Sinatra and Sqlite.
I am using below code to create sqlite database through Sinatra-

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
```

I am not getting any errors while creating entry in this database through my web application but I am not able to find "development.db" file in my current folder and even it's not there in any other folders.

Please suggest what might be the issue.
My whole code -

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")


class Student
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :row_id, Serial
  property :first_name, String
  property :last_name, String
  property :scu_email, String
  property :registered_on, Date
  property :program_name, String
  property :specialization, String
  property :expected_grad_year, String
  property :courses, Text
  property :username, String
  property :password, String
end

DataMapper.finalize
Student.auto_migrate!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Dir.pwd` with `__dir__` or `File.expand_path(__dir__)`

Comment: Tried above pattern too, not working. But when i use absolute path its working.

Comment: @Neha, is the development.db in the same directory as the Sinatra file? I'd also use `File.join` e.g `DataMapper.setup(:default, File.join("sqlite3://",File.expand_path(__dir__), "development.db")`.

Comment: Thanks alot @iain for the help. I figured out the issue. It was sqlite version issue. I downloaded wrong version for windows.